# Why does Windows display Your Battery is Very Low notification when the Battery has 100% charge?

Tags: windows-10, battery, desktop

Windows has been displaying a notification intermittently for two days now that my battery is very low, and that I should plug in my computer.  It's a desktop for one thing, not a notebook, and it is plugged in. In the Battery Saver settings the battery shows as having 100% charge. The TrippLite  battery backup LED shows full charge as well, and says that it's getting 123V.  The notification takes over my screen and shows up right in the middle of the screen. I'd like to know how to correct this Windows error.

Comment: Update / reinstall the power manager software - desktop computers have power level settings  Restart after this. Consider updating BIOS as well.

Comment: I have an APC true UPS backup unit and it does not interfere with my desktop computer at all. If there is TrippLite software, update that.

Comment: My experience has been that consumer battery backup software leaves a lot to be desired.